# Promise.then being resolved before previous .then with foreach completes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, promise

I'm running a semi-complex promise chain with a foreach loop in the middle. The issue I'm encountering is that the final `.then()` is being hit before the foreach loop completes resulting in a completely empty `dailyTotals` array.

```
fs.readdir(csvPath)
    .then(files => {
        // Define storage array
        var csvFiles = [];

        // Loop through and remove non-csv
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (file !== "README.md" && file !== ".gitignore") {
                csvFiles.push(file);
            }
        });

        return csvFiles;
    })
    .then(files => {
        var dailyTotals = [];

        files.forEach(filename => {
            const loadedFile = fs.createReadStream(csvPath + filename);

            var totalCases = 0;
            var totalDeaths = 0;
            var totalRecovered = 0;

            papa.parse(loadedFile, {
                header: true,
                worker: true,
                step: r => {
                    totalCases += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Confirmed);
                    totalDeaths += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Deaths);
                    totalRecovered += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Recovered);
                },
                complete: () => {
                    var dailyTotal = {
                        date: filename.replace(".csv", ""),
                        parsed: {
                            confirmed: totalCases,
                            deaths: totalDeaths,
                            recovered: totalRecovered
                        }
                    };

                    dailyTotals.push(dailyTotal);
                }
            });
        });

        return dailyTotals;
    })
    .then(dailyTotals => {
        console.log(dailyTotals);
    });
```

Is there a way to wait for that foreach loop to complete before resolving to the next `.then()`? The issue is directly on the foreach and the final `console.log(dailyTotals);`

Comment: Look into `Promise.all`

Comment: No. you will not get `.forEach` to wait. However, you hav other possibilities to achieve that with slightly different approaches:

1. Use a traditionel for-loop.

Comment: or ```Promise.allSettled```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I have to mention that there are alternative methods to `Array#forEach`:

- `Array#map` which is intended to create a new array by mapping the original one (the same what you do with `.forEach`), and
- `Array#filter` (its name speaks for itself).

The problem is, that you have a promise chain and a callback-based module. To mix them, use the `Promise` constructor and make use of `Promise.all`, to compose them into a single promise:

```js
fs.readdir(csvPath)
    .then(files => {

        // Filter out non-csv
        return files.filter(file => (file !== "README.md" && file !== ".gitignore"))
    })
    .then(files => {
        //Returning a Promise from then handler will be awaited
        return Promise.all(files.map(filename => {
            const loadedFile = fs.createReadStream(csvPath + filename);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                var totalCases = 0;
                var totalDeaths = 0;
                var totalRecovered = 0;

                papa.parse(loadedFile, {
                    header: true,
                    worker: true,
                    step: r => {
                        totalCases += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Confirmed);
                        totalDeaths += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Deaths);
                        totalRecovered += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Recovered);
                    },
                    complete: () => {
                        resolve( {
                          date: filename.replace(".csv", ""),
                          parsed: {
                            confirmed: totalCases,
                            deaths: totalDeaths,
                            recovered: totalRecovered
                          }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }));
    })
    .then(dailyTotals => {
        console.log(dailyTotals);
    });
```

You can even omit the first   `.then` handler, as `.filter` is a synchronous operation, and do everything inside a single `.then`:

```js
fs.readdir(csvPath)
    .then(files => {
        //Returning a Promise from then handler will be awaited
        return Promise.all(
            files
                //Filter here
                .filter(file => (file !== "README.md" && file !== ".gitignore"))
                //And map without a second then
                .map(filename => {
                    const loadedFile = fs.createReadStream(csvPath + filename);
                    return new Promise(resolve => {
                        var totalCases = 0;
                        var totalDeaths = 0;
                        var totalRecovered = 0;

                        papa.parse(loadedFile, {
                            header: true,
                            worker: true,
                            step: r => {
                                totalCases += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Confirmed);
                                totalDeaths += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Deaths);
                                totalRecovered += parseIntegerValue(r.data.Recovered);
                            },
                            complete: () => {
                                resolve( {
                                  date: filename.replace(".csv", ""),
                                  parsed: {
                                    confirmed: totalCases,
                                    deaths: totalDeaths,
                                    recovered: totalRecovered
                                  }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })
        );
    })
    .then(dailyTotals => {
        console.log(dailyTotals);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

No. you will not get your promise to wait for `.forEach` to before returning. If your `.forEach` function includes asynchronous code, you should not be using that.
Instead you can go with slightly different approaches:

1. Use a traditionel for-loop, as it is blocking.
2. Create a range promises `.map`, similar to what you did with .`forEach`, which I would recommend like:

```js
const promises = [array with your values].map(() => {
   // If you are running in a node env, you can also make the function async instead of returning a promise
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // Do what you need to
       if (error) {
          reject(error);
       }

       resolve(<insert the value that should be returned here>);

   });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => console.log('all promises done'));
```

See a working example of this with some simple console.log: https://jsfiddle.net/3ghmsaqj/

Comment: I'm not following... this is very hard for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: I updated my example. Can you check again and see if it makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second `then` has async code, `papa.parse()` so your for each in the second `then` will be completing synchronously with empty values, and therefore the final `then` will be executing with those empty values. You need to only return from the second `then` block when your async code completes

You will have to resolve promises in the `complete` callbacks, and use the likes of `Promise.all` to detect when all the `complete` callbacks are executed

1) change your for each to a map..

`const arrayPromises= files.map(... Etc)`

2) return a promise from your map callback.

`files.map((file) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {... Everything from your current foraeach}))`

3) revolve your promise from within the `complete` callback

`reolve()`

4) use `return Promise.all(arrayPromises)`

Comment: Can you explain this with code? This is very hard to follow with just text.

Comment: I'm on my phone, it would be hard to edit your attempt. Have a look at Promise.all docs. You will need to create an array of promises that represent your for loop and resolve each of the promises in the `complete` callback. You will `return Promise.all(arrayPromises)` in the second `then`. Basically your for loop contains async code. You only want to return when all of the async actions have completed. At the minute your second `then` is returning before the async code is complete